# Yahoo YUI DataTable.DataSource, anyway to simple update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, yui, yahoo

Is there a simple way to update a DataTable through a request rather then having to request the entire result set again?

currently im doing this:

```
    // register add modules event
Y.one('#add_modules').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    table.datasource.load({ 
        request: 'module_id=' + Y.one('#model').get('value') + '&module_count=' + Y.one('#module_count').get('value') + '&array_id=' + <?php echo $pv_array->id; ?>
    }); 
});
```

Although this removes any existing data and populates the table with the request result where as i want to simply "update" the table rather then having to request the whole result set again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a new Record to the RecordSet (recordSet is the repository for DataTable data) using [recordSet.add](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Recordset.html#method_add)  method

```
var item = {}; 
      item.module_id =  Y.one('#model').get('value');
      item.module_count = Y.one('#module_count').get('value');
      item.array_id = <?php echo $pv_array->id; ?>;

//get record set
var rs = table.get('recordset');
rs.add(item);
```

Comment: thanks i will try that, although now thinking about it it may be better to always send the whole set back as another user may be editing it in the mean time... keeping it more up-to-date.